# I want to echo all the values of the arrays using foreach loop within a function

Tags: php, function, foreach

I was trying to echo all the values of the `$sel_arrays` using the foreach loop within a function called `country()`. I was using the loop within the `country()` function and return the value `$sel`. But it does output only the single value **Bangladesh**. I want to get the all values of the `$sel_arrays`.Though I know that foreach loops iterates all the arrays values, But these codes does not give my expected result. Below my codes...

```
    <?php 
    function country() {
        $sel_arrays = array('Banglasesh','Pakistan','USA','India','Italy');

        foreach( $sel_arrays as $sel ) {
            return $sel;
        }
    }
    echo country(); // output only Bangladesh. That i ain't wanting.
    ?>
```

I did not get it how it is happening. Please help to get all the values of the array.

Comment: Instead of `return $sel;` do `echo $sel;`

Comment: Why you are using foreach loop, if you need to get $sel_arrays.. Just return $sel_arrays variable and remove foreach loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `returns`, and then exits the function, in the first iteration. This is how `return` works. To work around it, you could add all the values to a string, and echo that string instead.

```
function country() {
    $sel_arrays = array('Banglasesh','Pakistan','USA','India','Italy');

    $result = "";
    foreach( $sel_arrays as $sel ) {
        $result .= $sel." ";
    }
    return $result;
}
echo country(); // outputs everything, separated by a space
```

Reference

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function country() {
    $sel_arrays = array('Banglasesh','Pakistan','USA','India','Italy');

    foreach( $sel_arrays as $sel ) {
        echo $sel;
    }
}

country(); // output only Bangladesh. That i ain't wanting.
```